# for-each-group in combination with tokenize to collect all possible values from attribute

Tags: foreach, tokenize, xslt-3.0

I’m once again over my head with creating the proper XSLT (3.0) for having a distinct list of persons mentioned in my text.

The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <rs ref="#1">Romeo</rs>, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <rs ref="#2"
        >Julia</rs> diam nonumy eirmod <rs ref="#2 #4">family</rs> invidunt ut labore et <other corresp="#3">Dolores</other></p>
```

I'm trying to get a list of all distinct values of either @ref or @corresp. Note that there can be two values in @ref or @corresp, so it needs to be tokenized.

The result could be like this:

```
<values>
    <a>#1</a>
    <a>#2</a>
    <a>#3</a>
    <a>#4</a>
</values>
```

In my real world usage i will use the received values to look up a list of persons in another file.

So far this is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::*[self::rs or self::other]" group-by="@ref">
            <a>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@ref"/>
            </a>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I fail to integrate the tokenize(@ref, ' ') as well as that the values searched for are in either @ref or @corresp. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this(edit):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">

  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:variable name="numbers" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="rs/@ref|other/@corresp"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <values>
      <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($numbers)">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
        <a>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </a>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </values>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:sequence select="tokenize(.,'\s+')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This work's! As there are other attributes I had to tweak the variable by seperating the different possibilites with  "|", i.e. select="rs/@ref|other/@corresp"

Comment: @martinanton: great. I will change the code like that.

Comment: I tweaked it some more: With <xsl:variable name="numbers" as="xs:string*">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="rs/@ref|other/@corresp"/></xsl:variable> I could do away with the template for the attributes which produced some unwanted results

Comment: @martinanton, your last comment doesn't seem to make sense, given your statement that you also need to tokenize the attribute values. With that change you have posted I don't see where you tokenize values.

Comment: Just to give an update. My way was wrong and I had to revisit this problem. I did solve the unwanted results now by using "mode" on apply-templates and xsl:template match="@*"